# Have svn console in focus when performing an svn operation in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse

Is there a way to have the console focus on the SVN output when doing an SVN operation (such as update or commit)?

It's annoying to have to manually switch to that console.

Comment: +1 I would be interested in an answer aswell!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just open preferences to Team > SVN > Console and check the box "Show SVN console automatically when command is run"

Answer (score 1):

Window > Preferences > Team > SVN > Console

select "On output" to "Show console automatically"